# How to run .NET 5 WPF app without exe and console

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 WPF application built for AnyCPU platform.
In the project file i have:
WinExe
net5.0-windows

The output folder contains all dll and an exe but when i run the exe on a 32 bits windows i get this message:

> This version of software.exe is not compatible with the version of windows
> you're running. Check your computer's system information to see
> whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the
> program, and then contact the software publisher.

To ease deployment and run, I want to have only 1 build and 1 shortcut no matter the target system.
So my initial solution was to run the application using dotnet.exe and having the core dll as a parameter.

> dotnet.exe software.dll

The WPF application start and run fine but the console with the dotnet command line is kept open during the application lifetime.

Is there a solution to get rid of the console when I start the WPF application using dotnet.exe ?

Comment: Have you checked your build configuration in visual studio?  Each project can have different target cpus settings within the solution.

Comment: Hi @newky2k thanks for the advice. I'm aware of this possibility and this is the workaround i use for now. All my projects targets AnyCPU platform except WPF project which targets x86. Still this is a workaround for me hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

No solution without exe file at this time, so as a workaround I found a way to produce both 32bit and 64bit exe.

In the Visual Studio build configuration manager, I added x86 and x64 platforms.
Which updated the csproj with

```
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64</Platforms>
```

Then I added in csproj

```
    <AssemblyName>MySoftware-$(Platform)</AssemblyName>
```

When I build the solution, it automatically append the targeted platform to the exe and dll for the platform.

```
MySoftware-x86.exe
MySoftware-x86.dll
MySoftware-x64.exe
MySoftware-x64.dll
```

Finally, I call "dotnet.exe build" twice for both x86 and x64 using a script.

Answer (score 1):

> To put all this together, a 32-bit machine can run anything with a PE
> set to PE32, but nothing with a PE of PE32+. A 64-bit machine can run
> your file in 64-bit mode as long as 32BIT is 0, but if 32BIT is 1 then
> it must use WOW64.

https://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2010/02/sorting-out-the-confusion-32-vs-64-bit-clr-vs-native-cs-vs-cpp/

> Why would you want to compile a .NET assembly specific to 32-bit or
> X64, or IA? Usually because you're P/Invok'ing into a x64 specific
> native dll.
> The interesting things that corflags tell us are these:
>
> - CLR Header: The compiler version...2.0 is .NET 1.1, 2.5 is .NET 2.0
>   and 3.0 is .NET 3.5. Don't ask. ;)
> - PE (Portable Executable): PE32 is 32bit and PE32+ is 64-bit.
> - 32BIT: Are we asking to force 32-bit
>   execution or not?

[www.hanselman.com/blog/32bitness-and-64bitness-and-migrating-dasblog-on-iis7-and-aspnet-under-vista64](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/32bitness-and-64bitness-and-migrating-dasblog-on-iis7-and-aspnet-under-vista64)